# How to handle google maps events in jasmine test framework

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, backbone-events

I am trying to write Javascript tests for Google Maps using the jasmine framework. What I am trying to do is initiate the map and change the bounds (zoom out) and test that the map was correctly zoomed out.

The problems I am encountering are that jasmine doesn't seem to have any way to handle events. Jasmine has the `spyOn()` method that looks for a usage of a method (not an event). There is also the `waits()` method in jasmine that waits a specific amount of time. None of these methods are spot on for working with events. Does anybody have any experience with events in jasmine?

The code I'm working with:

```
describe('Map view', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        $('body').append("<div data-role='page' id='page-map'><div id='map_canvas'></div></div>");

        this.view = new MapView({el: $('#map_canvas')});
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $('body div#page-map').remove();
    });

    describe('zoom to a new bound in the map', function () {
        it('should set map bounds correctly', function () {
            this.view.zoomToBounds(this.fixtures.Locations.valid.bounds);
    
            google.maps.event.addListener(this.view.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
                // expect() doesn't work in this context.. (ex: expect(5).toEqual(1) will pass)
                expect(this.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat()).toBeGreaterThan(self.fixtures.Locations.valid.bounds.minLat);
                expect(this.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()).toBeGreaterThan(self.fixtures.Locations.valid.bounds.minLng);
                expect(this.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()).toBeLessThan(self.fixtures.Locations.valid.bounds.maxLat);
                expect(this.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()).toBeLessThan(self.fixtures.Locations.valid.bounds.maxLng);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The backbone view will initiate, and the Google map will render. The `zoomToBounds` method works fine, but it's when I want to check the result that I run into some problems. Inside the `google.maps.event.addListener()` clause the (jasmine) `expect()` calls doesn't seem to work .

The best way to do this would of course be to use jasmine methods for catching the event directly, but I haven't figured out a way to do this.

Anybody here has any idea on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> The best way to do this would of course be to use jasmine methods for
>   catching the event directly

Have you tried using the jasmine spies to spy on the prototype of the object that has the events bound on it? I think your events might be bound before the spies are setup:

Here is a simple example (in coffeescript)

```
  it 'calls render when a model is added to the collection', ->
    spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'render')
    view = new MyView({
      collection : new Backbone.Collection([])
    })
    view.collection.add({})
    expect(view.render).toHaveBeenCalled()
```